# ¿Cual es el equivalente a una tarea asíncrona (AsinckTask<>)de Java en C#?

Tags: java, android, c#, visual-studio, asincronismo

yo me dedico a desarrollar para Android pero ahora estoy involucrado en un proyecto que involucra un desarrollo para Escritorio en C#

Hace algún tiempo había creado esta clase que extiende de la clase AsyncTask, esta clase lo que hace es hacer un GET a una url y devolver el resultado como un jsonString

```
blic class LectorJsonHttp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private LectorJsonHttpResultado lectorJsonHttpResultado;
boolean lecturaCorrecta = false;

public LectorJsonHttp(LectorJsonHttpResultado lectorJsonHttpResultado) {
    this.lectorJsonHttpResultado=lectorJsonHttpResultado;


}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... httpUrl) {
    String jsonString="error";
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy Policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(Policy);

        HttpClient objCliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext objContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet objGet = new HttpGet(httpUrl[0]);

        HttpResponse objResponse = objCliente.execute(objGet, objContext);
        HttpEntity objEntidad = objResponse.getEntity();
        jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(objEntidad, "UTF-8");
        if(!jsonString.equals("error"))lecturaCorrecta = true;
    }catch (Exception E)
    {
        lecturaCorrecta = false;
    }

    return  jsonString;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {

    lectorJsonHttpResultado.abstractMtdJsonString(jsonString,lecturaCorrecta);

    super.onPostExecute(jsonString);


}
```

Ahora en el proyecto c# necesito hacer lo mismo, eh investigado un buen rato pero no encuentro algo realmente entendible ya que las tareas asíncronas en C# no tienen un método postExecute que se pueda utilizar para enviar datos al hilo principal por medio de una Interface, espero que me puedan dar algún consejo o una pista para poder hacer esto, de antemano gracias

Comment: La equivalente en C# sería `Task` de `Systen.Threading.Tasks` y por lo general son mas completas que los `AsyncTask`.  Puedes ver un ejemplo aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565090/getting-the-response-of-a-asynchronous-httpwebrequest

Comment: Puedes crear un hilo y hacerlo ahí también.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para la programación asíncrona existen varias opciones en C#. Puedes usar [`BackGroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) o como ya te han dicho en algun comentario, [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). Yo te recomendaría esta última ya que es mas moderna y potente.

Para el caso que expones, lo único que necesitas es usar `HttpClient` en un método asíncrono. Aquí te pongo un ejemplo muy sencillo de como descargar una página usando `GetAsync` y `Task`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     DescargarJson();
}

static async void DescargarJson()
{
    var r = await Descargar("http://stackoverflow.com");
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}

static async Task<string> Descargar(string url)
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using(var r = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)))
        {
            string result = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tenia la duda si al llamar la tarea asíncrona desde un método asíncrono el resultado que se recibe en el método se recibía sobre el hilo de la tarea asíncrona pero parece que no ya que me permite acceder a los controles del form sin problemas de contexto

Comment: @AlvaroFabianM debes tener pendiente algo. Los valores despues del await  estan en riesgo. A parte de Java Android, estoy en Android C# (Xamarin Android) y me ha pasado que los Activitys se destruyen antes de llegar el resultado y explota.  Por ejemplo si ejecuto un `Task` y cierro el `Activity`, como ese valor corre en un hilo diferente, la aplicacion me explotaba al intentaba realizar operaciones con un `Activity` destruido. Si vas a utilizar métodos en clases que se pueden destruir antes de llegar el valor te puede causar  `NullPointerException` u `ObjectDisposedException`. Buena suerte.